# Why am I getting a JSON exception while calling .getJSONObject()?

Tags: java, json, api, content-management-system, aem

I want to generate JSON with URI within the JSON response but I'm getting JSON exception when I tried to get a value of the key. Here fragmentdataservice is to get JSON data and it working fine and I'm working on API creation with content fragments.

```java
String requestURI = req.getRequestURI();
String contentFragmentName = requestURI.substring(requestURI.indexOf('.') +
    1, requestURI.lastIndexOf('.'));

resp.setContentType("application/json");
response = fragmentDataService.getContentFragment(contentFragmentName);

String contentReference = response.getJSONObject("poolingInfo").toString();
JSONObject contentData = fragmentDataService.getContentFragment(contentReference);
response.put("poolingInfo", contentData);
```

Comment: What's the exception you're getting? Are you sure the response is a valid JSON document?

Answer (score 0):

JSON exception will be thrown if you're trying to read a `String` data or a `JSONArray` data as a `JSONObject` using `getJSONObject()` method.
If you're not sure what's the type of object that's being returned then first use:

```
Object temp = response.get("poolingInfo");
if(null != temp && temp instanceof JSONObject) {
    String contentReference = ((JSONObject) temp).toString();
}
```